# Comparing the two feature sets

Tags: database, classification, svm, feature-extraction

I am working on a classification of two feature sets derived from a dataset. We first obtain two feature matrices derived from two feature extraction methods. Now, I need to compare them. However, the recognition accuracy for two feature sets, reaches almost the same recognition accuracy (using 10-fold cross validation by SVM). My question is:

- Is there a way to design a meaningful experiment to show the difference between the two methods? What are your suggestions?

Note: I already saw the similar questions in stackoverflow, however, I am looking for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- Perform a dimensionality reduction on the features in their respective spaces. This will allow you to see differences in the distribution of data points. Kudos if you apply a kernel, being the one used by the SVM (linear kernel otherwise).
- Do distribution testing on the features to see if they differ much.
- Augment the predictions into an output space, and see distance between the vectors.